# Can the computer that I'm (p)ssh'ing into be showing different than the original $PATH under certain circumstances?

Tags: unix, ssh, path, remote-access

I'm using this tool called [pssh](http://www.theether.org/pssh/docs/0.2.3/pssh-HOWTO.html) to ssh into a number of hosts together

The syntax to use it is:

```
pssh [OPTIONS] command [...]
```

For example:

```
pssh -h hosts.txt uptime
```

Here hosts.txt is the file that contains the ip addresses of all of my hosts.
The command mentioned above works just fine. Even if I replace uptime by ls it works fine and shows me the correct contents of all the files on the respective machines.

The problem is, if I replace that command with echo $PATH then it shows me my path

If I use this command:

```
pssh -h ips.txt which java
```

then for all the hosts it shows me this error:

```
which: no java in (/usr/local/bin:/bin:/usr/bin)
```

And if I ssh into just ONE of the hosts manually using the normal ssh command ()

and I execute the which command or see the $PATH variable, then is see this:

```
-bash-3.2$ echo $PATH
/home/xx/bin64:/home/xx/bin:/usr/kerberos/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/bin:/usr/bin
-bash-3.2$ which java
/home/xx/bin/java
-bash-3.2$
```

So this shows that at least that one machine has java installed and the right path configured. So can someone tell me why can't I get this command working for all the hosts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The server(s) you are connecting to probably set a different `$PATH` depending on whether or the shell that is run remotely is a login or interactive shell or not. When you ssh interactively, an interactive, login shell is invoked on the server. When you ssh non-interactively, a non-interactive, non-login shell is invoked (with a `-c` option to directly run the specified command without entering interactive mode).

Many shells source different startup files depending on whether they are invoked as login shells and/or interactive shells. For example, bash reads `~/.profile` (or variants) only when it is a login shell, and `~/.bashrc` only when it is an intractive shell. The server probably sets up a `$PATH` that includes the directory for Java from one of those startup files.

The solution to this is to set up environment variables like `$PATH` from `/etc/environment` instead of from shell startup files.